# Html href attribut for previous and next button in a one page site?

Tags: html, button, single-page-application, href

i made a minimalist one page blog with html/css.

I want to add two button to go up (previous post) or down (next post) on a fixed side menu. I wonder witch attribut i have to give to the class "href", to move automatically up or down **in the same page **(and not to a specific anchor/another page).

Every solution are welcome ! Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the [tour]. Your "question" at present is well below the standard required on this site

Comment: I don't know if it's possible without using anchors... Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: Hi Miss Skooter. Actually, If i use an specific anchor, then the button will only get to there, and not further... I want that reader can navigate to a post title to another with the same button. A bit like a carrousel, but in an easier way. As the site is only a single page with list of blogpost. Do you know if there is any universal anchor or class i can use ?

Comment: You could use anchors dynamically, not necessarily staticly. something like having each article with an id: `#article1`, `#article2`, etc. when you add the articles (which im assuming is through js) and map the href the same way. If it's the same buttons being used to navigate between the articles, then just update the href attribute in JS after scrolling

Comment: Either way, you should write your own implementation and have us help you debug it if you face issues. As it stands, your question is too broad for anyone to answer without doing an entire implementation that may or may not work for your use case which we know next to nothing about

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision. It's the first time a post an question on stackoverflow... I'll try to be more precise and add my entire implementation next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it with anchors and href in a might not work. This should work for your solution, of course you need to add your own restraints. Clicking on a button will change the index to a list with all sections.

index.html

```html
<button onclick="step(1)">next</button>
<button onclick="step(-1)">previous</button>

<h1 id="section1">Section 1</h1>
<h1 id="section2">Section 2</h1>
```

main.js

```js
var current = 0;
var sections = ['section1', 'section2'];

function step(incr) {
    current += incr;
    window.location.href = '#'+sections[current];
}
```

You replace the anchor by using an increment on a click event.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the solution.  i add your script in the page. It works very well with next button (thank !!), but actually not for the previous button (the link get to #undefined). I'm don't have a lot of javascript knowledge... If have an idea to fix it, you're very welcome.

Comment: @CoralineGr try clicking next twice and then try previous. Add constraints so you can't click on previous if there is no previous option. If my question helped, could you upvote and select it as the answer please? If you have more questions, let me know!

Comment: Hi max, indeed, it works well so far. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hi Max, you mention constraints to block the click when there's no previous option. What  Js code would you use for that ? I'm not a master in JS (it's an euphemismus... hum). if you can quick help, you're very welcome. Thanks !

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp < this might help